# How to fix the size and the color of my custom marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4

I added in my mapView (google maps) a custom markers

```
func addMarker(place:EClass) {    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let coordinates = place.location  else {
            return
        }
        self.destination = coordinates

       //Custom marker
       let markerImage = UIImage(named: "marker 2 copy.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
       let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)

       self.marker = GMSMarker()
       self.marker?.position = coordinates
       self.marker?.title = place.name
       self.marker?.map = self.mapView
       self.marker?.iconView = markerView
       self.mapView.selectedMarker = self.marker

       if self.currentLocation != nil {
           self.drawPath(startLocation: self.currentLocation!, endLocation: coordinates)
       }        
    }
}
```

but the size of it when i run the application is to big, so how can i adjust the size? I have to do it programmatically or i have to change the size of the png i added in my project? Also the color is not same of my png (that is red and black), when i run the application my custom marker appears white.

Comment: if you are using `.alwaysTemplate` the you should set a tintColor for your markerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `GMSMarker.icon` not `GMSMarker.iconView`

```
let markerImage = UIImage(named: "marker 2 copy.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
self.marker?.icon = self.image(markerImage, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))

//Image function
fileprivate func image(_ originalImage:UIImage, scaledToSize:CGSize) -> UIImage {
    if originalImage.size.equalTo(scaledToSize) {
        return originalImage
    } 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scaledToSize, false, 0.0)
    originalImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scaledToSize.width, height: scaledToSize.height))
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```